# How can get email from current user logged in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, react-admin

I am working in admin website using react-admin framework.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Readme.html

I need to show current user email that is logged. How can I get this functionality?

Regards

Comment: hello, if you are consuming data from some API that you have made you can achieve that by calling the endpoint that brings the user information  back inside the response.

Comment: @ricardoleivasikic. I am using react-admin with Firebase. I am searching to obtain current user logged email. With this value I want to use filter functionality, for example: <List {...props} filter={{ createdby: loggedUserEmail }}...

Comment: Same here but instead I want to get the user id. Is there a way to access the loggedin user object?

Comment: @user2316075 if you got this one answered you could mark it as accepted or you could try to clarify your question if neither answer is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

There is a dedicated hook to retrieve this kind of data called [`useGetIdentity`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#usegetidentity-hook)

**ORIGINAL:**

I have implemented a custom verb in the `authProvier` similarly to the [Dwadelfri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63031321/6355024)'s answer. It gets pretty handy because you can access it through the built in hook `useAuthProvider`

inside `authProvider.js`

```
import decodeJwt from 'jwt-decode';

const getCurrentUser = () => {
    // the place where you saved user's data on login
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    const decodedToken = decodeJwt(user.token);

    return { 
        ...user,
        ...decodedToken,
    };
}

export default {
    login: loginHandler,
    logout: logoutHandler,
    checkAuth: checkAuthHandler,
    checkError: checkErrorHandler,
    getPermissions: getPermissionsHandler,
    //custom verbs
    signUp: signUpHandler,
    getCurrentUser: getCurrentUser,
};
```

Then the code looks pretty neat when you decide to call it:

```
const authProvider = useAuthProvider();
const user = authProvider.getCurrentUser();
```

Comment: no you don't need this!  just use the "useGetIdentity" hook already provided by react-admin

Comment: This answer was posted before the hook was introduced - I'll update the answer for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

I only found this kinda hacky way, I'm looking for better alternative but for right now I'm using this to get the user id which could be used to get other stuff via the dataProvider.

```
import decodeJwt from 'jwt-decode';

const getUserId = () => {
  return decodeJwt(localStorage.getItem("token")).sub;
}
```

this asumes you use [jwt](https://jwt.io/) and your token includes the user id

```
const token = jwt.sign({ sub: user.id}, config.secret);
```

Comment: hey Dwadelfri look at my comment on other post about useGetIdentity

Answer (score 0):

the solution that I got is the following:

Inside your Data page (posts.js for instance)

1. First import the following Firebase package

`import firebase from 'firebase/app';`

2. Then get the connected user straight from the firebase context as the following:

`const email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;`

3. The filter part would be the following:

````
   <List
   {...props}
   filter={{ createdby: email }}>```
````